# How do I choose records with equal values in some column?

Tags: sql, database

How do I choose records with equal values for the last name column?

This is the table `empl`:

```
 ide    fn     ln     debt
 3421   jed    trt    43
 354    jed    res    43
  43    ged    hjkhg  79
  73    ghghg  gfgf   79
 456    jkl    gdfg   78
 532    kkhg   vjv    23
  45    ki     vt     79
 243    k      vt     78
```

I need to choose the last two records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ide, fn, ln, debt
FROM empl
WHERE ln IN
(
    SELECT ln
    FROM empl
    GROUP BY ln
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do:

```
select ide, fn, ln, debt
from empl
where ln in
  (
    select ln from empl
    group by ln
    having count(1) > 1
  )
order by ln
```